# Sending data from JSON response to CSV

Tags: python, json, csv, export-to-csv

I am almost done with my code, but I am getting stuck at one of the places.

```
import requests as rq
import pandas as pd
import json as js
import csv
import xlsxwriter

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
temp_link = 'apidev.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/200.json?language=en&apikey=hoArfRosT1215'
for i in range(1,10):

    abc = 'http://'+temp_link.replace('200',str(i))
    response = rq.get(abc).json()
    j_nrml = json_normalize(response)
    j_nrml.to_csv('wdata.csv',sep = ",")
    print(i)
```

The temp_link variale has a dummy text on which we are prefixing http and replacing the number 200 with numbers 1 to 10 which inturn results in json texts.
The issue is while writing the normalized json into the csv, it only sends the last retrieved JSON and not all 10. Any idea how to get all the 10 records in csv

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Because you're writing to the same file name inside the loop, meaning you completely delete the file contents from the last iteration

Comment: You should append to the dataframe each time through the loop, and then write it to the file at the end.

Comment: So is it like the data frame is getting overwritten everytime it loops?